# How to read multinode xml & save the info in java

Tags: java, xml

I have the below xml file

```
<x no="1">
    <act>action 1</act>
    <vfy>
        <check>check 1</check>
        <expectedResult>exp result 1</expectedResult>
        <failedMessage>failed msg 1</failedMessage>
    </vfy>
    <vfy>
        <check>check 2</check>
        <expectedResult>exp result 2</expectedResult>
        <failedMessage>failed msg 1</failedMessage>
    </vfy>
</x>

<x no="2">
    <act>action 2</act>
    <vfy>
        <check>check 1</check>
        <expectedResult>exp result 1</expectedResult>
        <failedMessage>failed msg 1</failedMessage>
    </vfy>
    <vfy>
        <check>check 2</check>
        <expectedResult>exp result 2</expectedResult>
        <failedMessage>failed msg 1</failedMessage>
    </vfy>
</x>
```

I need to read this xml file through java (Dom parsar) & want to save the data into a class, so that another class can use those data easily.

Comment: 1) Your document is not correct, it **must** show only a single root document. 2) To save data in a class, it might useful and relevant for you to use JAXB.

Comment: Use either SAX parser if you want less data from big XML file or JAXB if you need to parse most of the data out of XML

Comment: What have you tried so far? If `xml` elements are known (static) then use `DocumentBuilderFactory` and parse `xml` and traverse all child nodes and set data to your POJO.

Comment: @potame sorry, here i forget to mention the root element.

Comment: @Vicky xml elements are static in my case. I use DocumentBuilderFactory as well. There is no problem for reading purpose, but I face problem to save the data to a class. How will be the class structure to store these data.